# Updating ca-certificates in distroless docker image

Tags: docker, ssl, cacerts

How can I run update-ca-certificates
(https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html) **while** the docker container is running? Meaning updating `/etc/ssl/certs` while the docker build process and copying the updated certs to `etc/ssl/certs` is not an option for me. I need to be able to update the certificates while the container is running. I checked this post: [Docker distroless image how to make update-ca-certificates available inside the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65043442/docker-distroless-image-how-to-make-update-ca-certificates-available-inside-the) but couldnt see anything concrete that could be useful.

Comment: Why not mount a volume where those certs are?

Comment: And run the update-ca-certificates inside a different docker container and share the updated result with the distroless?

Comment: Yes or use a multistage docker image. One with a distro, then the final one

Comment: But I want to be able to restart the container and then rerun the update-ca-certificates in the entrypoint of my container... can that be done with a multistage docker image?

Comment: Ideally containers should be immutable